# How to save Integer instead of string in UIpickerView to database?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uipickerview

I am using UIpickerview to save a value to the database , 
but I want to save Integer instead of string and keep string to just show to the user

[this my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqW9L.png)

to more explain :
If the user chooses mecca I want to save 1 in the database , if select Cairo save 2 to database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `row` delegate method integer and add 1 as it's indexing starts from 0

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    let stored = row + 1   
    print(stored)
}
```

Comment: if array element position will then change above code will not work

Comment: the array position will stay the same as the op doesn't change it and if so the above code will work with latest change also

Comment: This will definitely work if the array element position will remain the same.